# Array manipulation (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, hierarchy

I have an array like this one :

```
Array
{
   'property1.subproberty11' => "xxxxx",
   'property1.subproberty12' => "yyyy",
   'property2.subproberty21.subproperty211' => "zzzzzz",
   'property2.subproberty21.subproperty212' => "wwwww",
   'property2.subproberty22' => "yyyy",
   ....
```

That needs to be changed into something like :

```
Array
(
[property1] => Array
    (
            ['subproberty11'] => "xxxxx"
            ['subproberty12'] => "yyyy"
    )

[property2] => Array
    (
        [subproperty21] => Array
            (
                [subproperty211] => "zzzzzz"
                [subproperty212] => "wwwwww"
            )
        ['subproberty22'] => "yyyy"

    )
   ...
```

I can't find a smart way of doing this, can someone help me ?

So, far, i have thought of this kind of algorithm :

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $key => $value)
{
    $subkeys = explode('.', $key);
    $ss = array();
    for($ii = 0 ; $ii < count($subkeys) ; $ii++)
    {
        $ss[] = "['".$subkeys[$ii]."']";
        if ($ii < count($subkeys) -1)
            eval('$new_array'.implode('',$ss).' = array();');
    }
    eval('$new_array'.implode('',$ss)." = '".$value."';');
}
```

I think we can do better, for example maybe we can avoid duplicating data by creating a new array ?

Comment: How would you describe a "smart" way? What have you tried already and where did it fail you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working example:

```
function nestedKeysArray($input) {
    $array = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $keys = explode('.', $key);
        if (count($keys) == 1) {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $nested = &$array;
            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                if (!isset($nested[$k]))
                    $nested[$k] = array();
                $nested = &$nested[$k];
            }
            $nested = $value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

$input is array like first one from the question.

**EDIT:**
Changing original array, without copy:

```
function nestedKeysArray(&$input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $keys = explode('.', $key);
        if (count($keys) > 1) {
            $nested = &$input;
            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                if (!isset($nested[$k]))
                    $nested[$k] = array();
                $nested = &$nested[$k];
            }
            $nested = $value;
            unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working with this array : 
    Array(
    'property1.subproberty11' => "xxxxx",
    'property1.subproberty12' => "yyyy",
    'property2.subproberty21.subproperty211' => "zzzzzz",
    'property2.subproberty21.subproperty212' => "wwwww",
    'property2.subproberty22' => "yyyy",
    'property3' => "xxx"    
    );

Comment: But anyway nesting have to be correct. It will not deal with misconception like Array( 'property1' => "xxxxx", 'property1.subproberty12' => "yyyy");

Comment: Does it make sense to modify the function so that it works on the original array, not on a copy ?

Comment: Only if array is so large you couldn't assign second one of such size =) Anyway, it could be done easily, I've added this to the answer. But changing the original array could break order of keys and you will have to spent additional resources for sorting if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Some untested code, to give you the direction you could take.

Just loop through the array;

```
function SplitArray($properties) {
    foreach($properties as $item=>$property) {
        $properties[$item] = explode('.',$property, 2);
        if(strpos($properties[$item][1], '.') === false)) {}
        else {
            $properties[$item][1] = SplitArray($properties[$item][1]);
        }
    }
    return $properties;
}
```